# REACT: How to set the state in the child and access it in the parent, receiving undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am building this project to try and improve my understanding of react :), so I am a n00b and therefore still learning the ropes of extracting components, states, props etc =)

I have a child Component `DescriptionDiv`, its parent component is `PlusContent` and finally the parent component is `PlusContentHolder`. The user types some input into the `DescriptionDiv` which then, using a props/callback passes the user input to the `PlusContent`.

**My question/problem is:** after setting `useState()` in the `PlusContent` component, I am after a button click in the `PlusContentHolder` component, returned with an `undefined` in the console.log.

How come I cannot read the `useState()` in the next parent component, the `PlusContentHolder`?

I know that `useState()` is async so you cannot straight up call the value of the state in the `PlusContent` component, but shouldn't the state value be available in the `PlusContentHolder` component?

below is my code for the `DescriptionDiv`

```
import './DescriptionDiv.css';

const DescriptionDiv = props => {
    const onDescriptionChangeHandler = (event) => {
        props.descriptionPointer(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div className='description'>
            <label>
                <p>Description:</p>
                <input onChange={onDescriptionChangeHandler} type='text'></input>
            </label>
        </div>);
}

export default DescriptionDiv;
```

Next the code for the `PlusContent` comp

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DescriptionDiv from "./div/DescriptionDiv";
import ImgDiv from "./div/ImgDiv";
import "./PlusContent.css";
import OrientationDiv from "./div/OrientationDiv";

const PlusContent = (props) => {
  const [classes, setClasses] = useState("half");
  const [content, setContent] = useState();
    const [plusContent, setPlusContent] = useState({
    orientation: "left",
    img: "",
    description: "",
  });

  const onOrientationChangeHandler = (orientationContent) => {
    if (orientationContent == "left") {
      setClasses("half left");
    }
    if (orientationContent == "right") {
      setClasses("half right");
    }
    if (orientationContent == "center") {
      setClasses("half center");
    }
    props.orientationInfo(orientationContent);
  };


  const onDescriptionContentHandler = (descriptionContent) => {
    props.descriptionInfo(setPlusContent(descriptionContent));
    console.log(descriptionContent)
  };

  const onImageChangeHandler = (imageContent) => {
    props.imageInfo(imageContent);
    setContent(
      <>
        <OrientationDiv
          orientationPointer={onOrientationChangeHandler}
          orientationName={props.orientationName}
        /> {/*
        <AltDiv altPointer={onAltDivContentHandler} />
        <TitleDiv titlePointer={onTitleDivContentHandler} /> */}
        <DescriptionDiv descriptionPointer={onDescriptionContentHandler} />
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes}>
        <ImgDiv imageChangeExecutor={onImageChangeHandler} />
      {content}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlusContent;
```

and lastly the `PlusContentHolder`

```
import PlusContent from "../PlusContent";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const PlusContentHolder = (props) => {

  const onClickHandler = (t) => {
    t.preventDefault();
    descriptionInfoHandler();
  };

  const descriptionInfoHandler = (x) => {
      console.log(x)  // this console.log(x) returns and undefined 
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {props.contentAmountPointer.map((content) => (
        <PlusContent
          orientationInfo={orientationInfoHandler}
          imageInfo={imageInfoHandler}
          descriptionInfo={descriptionInfoHandler}
          key={content}
          orientationName={content}
        />
      ))}
      <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Generate Plus Content</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlusContentHolder;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the `descriptionInfoHandler()` function call prints `undefined` in its `console.log()` statement when you click the button, is because you never provide an argument to it when you call it from the `onClickHandler` function.

I think that it will print the description when you type it, however. And I believe the problem is that you need to *save* the state in the `PlusContentHolder` module as well.

I would probably add a `const [content, setContent] = useState()` in the `PlusContentHolder` component, and make sure to call `setContent(x)` in the `descriptionInfoHandler` function in `PlusContentHolder`.

Otherwise, the state will not be present in the `PlusContentHolder` component when you click the button.

Comment: Hey Frost, thanks for your answer, so that means I have two `useState()` running? One in `PlusContent` and another in `PlusContentHolder`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to only maintain a single state in the PlusContentHolder for orientation.
Here's a sample implementation of your use case

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const PlusContentHolder = () => {
  const [orientatation, setOrientation] = useState('');

  const orientationInfoHandler = (x) => {
    setOrientation(x);
  };
  const generateOrientation = () => {
    console.log('orientatation', orientatation);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <PlusContent orientationInfo={orientationInfoHandler} />
      <button onClick={generateOrientation}>generate</button>
    </>
  );
};

const PlusContent = ({ orientationInfo }) => {
  const onDescriptionContentHandler = (value) => {
    // your custom implementation here,
    orientationInfo(value);
  };
  return <DescriptionDiv descriptionPointer={onDescriptionContentHandler} />;
};

const DescriptionDiv = ({ descriptionPointer }) => {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    descriptionPointer(e.target.value);
  };
  return <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />;
};
```

I would suggest to maintain the `orientation` in redux so that its easier to update from the application.

Comment: Hey Erick, thanks for the reply, so the best solution in this case for me, would be to have the intermediary component holding the state, the `PlusContentHolder`? The reason I was trying to get the `PlusContent` comp to hold the state is because the `PlusContent` repeats alot in my app, and I wanted to gather all the data from the individual `PlusContent` comps and then in the `PlusContentHolder` collect all the individual data from the `PlusContent` and put into an array/json/object. But I'm a little bit at a loss on how to do that )=

Answer (score 1):

SetState functions do not return anything. In the code below, you're passing `undefined` to `props.descriptionInfo`

```js
const onDescriptionContentHandler = (descriptionContent) => {
    props.descriptionInfo(setPlusContent(descriptionContent));
 
};
```

This shows a misunderstanding of the use of state. Make sure you're reading about "lifting state" in the [docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components#lifting-state-up-by-example).

You're also declaring needless functions, e.g. `onDescriptionContentHandler` in your `PlusContent`. The `PlusContent` component could just pass the `descriptionInfoHandler` from `PlusContentHolder` prop directly down to `DescriptionDiv`, since `onDescriptionContentHandler` doesn't do anything except invoke `descriptionInfoHandler`.

You may want to consider restructuring your app so `plusContent` state is maintained in `PlusContentHolder`, and pass that state down as props. That state would get updated when `DescriptionDiv` invokes `descriptionInfoHandler`. It'd subsequently pass the updated state down as props to `PlusContent`.

[See my suggested flowchart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnMUW.png)

Comment: Hey Eric, thanks for the reply, yeah it is all a bit messy, I the `onDescriptionHandler` in `PlusContent` because before I was storing the state in `PlusContentHolder`, but am now trying to store the state in `PlusContent` itself. I am trying to do that because in `PlusContentHolder` I basically want to build an array with aaalll the data from the individual `PlusContent` props, that is my end goal. Thanks for your flowchart :D I'll give it a go restructuring my app like that and get back to you